# Characterization of finite morsphisms over $\operatorname{Spec }O_K$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, affine-schemes

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $O_K$. Now consider a finite  and dominant (this condition was added later) morphism of schemes:

$$\pi:X\to \operatorname{Spec }O_K$$

Do we have some results which tell us what is the scheme $X$? For instance if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, then one possibility is $X= \operatorname{Spec }O_L $. Then what else? Do we have some classification theorem for $X$?

**Edit:**
I'm trying to prove that when $X$ is integral then the unique possibility is 
$X=\operatorname{Spec }O_L$ for a finite extension $K\subset L$. Let $L$ be the function field of $X$, then by the valuative criterion of properness I get a morphism over $\operatorname{Spec }O_K$:
$$f: \operatorname{Spec }O_L\to X$$
The last step is to show that it is actually an isomorphism... Any suggestions?

Comment: If $X$ is reduced and irreducible, the only choice is what you write. Otherwise, there are other possibilities.

Comment: @Mohan Closed immersions are finite but not generally of that form.

Comment: I am assuming finite and dominant.

Comment: Why if $X$ is integral and $\pi$ is dominant, the unique choice is what I've written? Do you have a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a smoothness hypothesis, non-maximal orders give counterexamples, e.g. $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[2i]$ is finite dominant over $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$.